# How to loop through elements in selenium using Python?

Tags: html, selenium, loops

I would like to know how to loop through things in Selenium. Basically, I just want to make a for-loop to find all the "panel titles" that have earlier than a certain time and then an if statement that says if it has 4 golfers then I will click the book button.

I'm just not sure how you iterate through the xpaths to these things in HTML. All I have been able to do so far is just click on the correct Day with my code below, however I can't figure out

```
    ### Gets Edge driver and doesnt need extension update
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get(
        'https://teewire.net/granada/'
    )
    driver.maximize_window()
    pause(2)
    
    data_moment = "2022-10-30"
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//*[@id='gz-time-slot-calendar']//a[@data-moment='{data_moment}']").click()
    pause(5)
    
    data_moment = "2022-10-30"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//*[@id='gz-time-slot-calendar']//a[@data-moment='{data_moment}']").click()
pause(5)

    a = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='time-slots-container-id']//a[@class='{'panel-heading'}']")
    pause(2)
    for i in a:
        print(i.text)
```

Here's an attached file. [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrTTB.png)

Comment: I've never used selenium in I'm assuming javascript or java, but the C# has a plural find. So instead of "find_element" its "find_elements", that should return an array.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it is python. I did try find_element(s)

Comment: Which data you want to retrieve, Panel title means the time or View Rates or the count of golfers?

Comment: @AbiSaran I see, I didnt realize it carried all that information. I would just like to know the times really, and then eventually just make an if statement that says 
if 4 golfers:
   click the button containing that time slot.

Comment: Posted an answer, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
golfers_text = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".panel.panel-default.teetime .panel-body")

i = 0
for golfer_text in golfers_text:
    value = golfer_text.text
    print(value)
    if "Up to 4 golfers" in value:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='panel panel-default teetime']//div[@class='panel-body']/button)[" + str(i + 1) + "]").click()
        break
    print("------")
    i += 1
```

Comment: This is a great answer, Thank you so much this is super helpful. I have not seen that way of making a path with css selector. It seems like the most simplistic way of doing this.

Comment: Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation I found this:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
```

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

a quick example I wrote up is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.theregister.com/")
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//article')

first = elements[0]
```

Comment: This was helpful, you can get the elements with find_elements using the xpath